# R Fill backwards with flexible window based on number of rows in a separate column

Tags: r

I am trying to carry a value in one column backwards by a number of rows given in a second column and fill everything in between.

So column y mainly has 1s in it but might have individual numbers up to about 20 (in my real data, up to 3 in my example below). If the number in y is 20, I need the 19 rows before that row and that row itself to equal the value of x for the row where y is 20. If the value in y is 1 the output will just equal x.

`y` also has many NAs, these NAs are either legitimate NAs where I want an NA output or are placeholders where the filling should occur if a y value afterwards is > 1.

I thought I could use `dplyr::lead` but I cannot have a variable `n` value to look forwards a different number of steps, and it wouldn't fill inbetween, and I wondered about making a new, always increasing column and using `RcppRoll::roll_max` but have similar problems with the flexible window size.

Typically y-values in the lead up to a y > 1 will be 0 or NA, but if there were conflicts I would want to adopt the later value still eg in row 8 of my data frame y is 1 followed by y = 2 in row 9 so I want the value associated with row 9 in both cases. If y in NA and there is not covered by filling backwards, I want it to remain NA (or 0 would be fine)

Thanks for any thoughts

```r
 set.seed(1)
 test <- data.frame(x = sample(1:15,replace = F), y = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3,1,2,1,1,NA,NA,NA,2))
 desired_out <- test
 desired_out$out <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,11,11,11,8,8,12,5,NA,NA,14,14)
 desired_out
#>     x  y out
#> 1   9 NA  NA
#> 2   4 NA  NA
#> 3   7 NA  NA
#> 4   1  1   1
#> 5   2 NA  11
#> 6  13 NA  11
#> 7  11  3  11
#> 8   3  1   8
#> 9   8  2   8
#> 10 12  1  12
#> 11  5  1   5
#> 12  6 NA  NA
#> 13 15 NA  NA
#> 14 10 NA  14
#> 15 14  2  14
 
 #try adopting @sirius answer before I specified about the extra NAs
 test$y <- ifelse(is.na(test$y),0,test$y)
 test$out <- with( test, rep( x, y ) )
#> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, out, value = c(1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, : replacement has 11 rows, data has 15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things got a bit complex, but essentially calculate all the repeated x's for each y > 0, and then let subsequent x'es overwrite earlier ones

```r
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(x = sample(1:15,replace = F), y = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,3,1,2,1,1,NA,NA,NA,2))

desired_out <- test
desired_out$out <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,11,11,11,8,8,12,5,NA,NA,14,14)
desired_out

test %<>% mutate( id = seq(n()) ) %>%
    filter( !is.na(y) & y != 0  ) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice( rep(1,y) ) %>%
    mutate( id = rev( max(id)+1-1:n() ) ) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize( out = as.numeric(last(x)) ) %>%
    right_join( test %>% mutate( id=seq(n()) ) ) %>%
    arrange( id ) %>% select( -id ) %>% relocate( x, y, out )

identical( as.data.frame(test), desired_out ) ## TRUE

test
```

Output:

```
> test
# A tibble: 15 x 3
       x     y   out
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     9    NA    NA
 2     4    NA    NA
 3     7    NA    NA
 4     1     1     1
 5     2    NA    11
 6    13    NA    11
 7    11     3    11
 8     3     1     8
 9     8     2     8
10    12     1    12
11     5     1     5
12     6    NA    NA
13    15    NA    NA
14    10    NA    14
15    14     2    14
```

What the algorithm does, which after a few piped lines is no longer very clear, is the following:

1. temporarily add `id` as original row number
2. take away 0 and NA rows for `y`
3. repeat each row `y` times
4. within each such repeated row, create a new `id` that counts backwards (these will be the new row numbers for the x-values to
   go)
5. group by id again this time to let later values overwrite earlier values (so keep only the highest row number for any collision)
6. join these data back on the original data, using the newly calculated row numbers, repeated x's will now be inserted
7. sort and clean up

Comment: Hi thanks, this does address the bulk of the question I asked (and I like the simplicity) but I realise now my problem is a little more complicated than my example makes it. I'm updating now

Comment: Thank you. That is a bit of an epic pipe but it works well and goes well with my script as I already have a grouped data frame and would like to maintain those groups (I thought that was overly complicated to ask and I could handle afterwards, but yours will handle both)

Answer (score 2):

Sequencing and indexing to the rescue:

```
test$rn <- seq_len(nrow(test))
src     <- with(test[!is.na(test$y),],
                list(val = rep(x,y), idx = rep(rn,y) - sequence(y) + 1) )
test$out[src$idx] <- src$val
test$rn <- NULL

#    x  y out
#1   9 NA  NA
#2   4 NA  NA
#3   7 NA  NA
#4   1  1   1
#5   2 NA  11
#6  13 NA  11
#7  11  3  11
#8   3  1   8
#9   8  2   8
#10 12  1  12
#11  5  1   5
#12  6 NA  NA
#13 15 NA  NA
#14 10 NA  14
#15 14  2  14
```

I'm generating a row number, getting the row numbers prior to the key rows, and then overwriting those rows with repeats of the selected rows. Sometimes they specify the same location, but the later value will be taken as you can see in the output.

Should be pretty efficient as everything is vectorised and there's only one major assignment operation back to the original dataset for updating all the rows at once. Here's 4.5M rows processed in a fraction of a second:

```
test <- test[rep(1:15, 3e5),]

system.time({
  test$rn <- seq_len(nrow(test))
  src <- with(test[!is.na(test$y),],
              list(val = rep(x,y), idx = rep(rn,y) - sequence(y) + 1) )
  test$out[src$idx] <- src$val
  test$rn <- NULL
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.28    0.00    0.28
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nicely succinct answer and does everything I want, however I have given the answer to Sirius who just happened to fit in well with the fact that my real data is already a grouped data frame. Both answers worked both with example and my real data though so could be helpful to someone else.

Comment: @Sarah - no worries. To be clear, this code won't destroy any groupings you might already have, and you can pick up the result and pipe-away no problems.